# I have a 24 word seed and a passphrase - I need master private key

Tags: altcoin, blockchain-fork, mnemonic-seed, passphrase

there's a wallet initially created by trezor using a 24 word seed and 25th word passphrase. I need the master private key of this wallet (old P2PKH format) to get access to old fork coins.

However, the 24 word seed without the passphrase is still in use, so I can't risk entering them on a live computer.

How can I get the private key info of the 24+1 words without compromising the 24 words? Is there a tool that I can use on an offline machine?

Thanks!

Comment: Which forkcoin are you interested in? Trezor supports Bitcoin Cash, which is at 0.5% of Bitcoin's value, other forks are worth even less. This might not be worth your time or the risk of accidentally compromising your seed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy to use option, you can use Electrum to import your wallet from the seed. Once the wallet is imported you can get the master private key. This can be done completely offline. You can even download Electrum on another computer and transfer it to your offline machine.

Here are easy steps to follow for importing https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/

Once your wallet is imported, open up the console in Electrum and type `getmasterprivate()`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but couldn't find the passphrase option. Later I think I found it: on entering seed I must go to options, select both BIP39 and extra passphrase, which opens a dialog for passphrase after going to next dialog from seed. This might work, I'll try on offline PC with the real seed soon.